# Trying to delete from Android database but get a null object reference

Tags: java, android, listview

In the `TripList.java` class I have a listView that is populated with my trip destinations and dates into those separate Arrays. Now on each item in the listView I have an X which when clicked I want it to delete that item out of the database.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.nikscodingmachine.truckersexpence.DatabaseHelper.deleteData(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.nikscodingmachine.truckersexpence.TripList.getBack(TripList.java:185)
```

I've tried so many different things but nothing seems to work. I don't see why there is a null pointer if I am trying to reach into my database which has things stored in there already. It seems like once I am out of the onCreate cycle in the TripList and in the TruckAdapter class, coming back to `TripList.java` from `TruckAdapter.java` is where the issue is. I've tried making another class and passing data there but because some of these classes extend other classes it gives me errors when I try to do so. If anyone please show me how to do it right. Thank you very much, my classes are below.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;



public class TripList extends ActionBarActivity {
//Instance of my created database
public DatabaseHelper myDb;
private TruckAdapter adapter;

//my variables
private String destination;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
private ListView listView;

private String da;
private String mo;
private String ye;




//ArrayLists you populate from database so we can later use them in the list
private List destinationArray = new ArrayList();
private List monthArray = new ArrayList();
private List dayArray = new ArrayList();
private List yearArray = new ArrayList();
int[] deleteArray = {R.drawable.delete_button};

//Just an empty constructor
public TripList(){
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_trip_list);
    //Creating myDb class
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    //receiving information from InitialEntry
    destination = getIntent().getStringExtra("names");
    day = getIntent().getIntExtra("toDay", -1);
    month = getIntent().getIntExtra("toMonth", -1);
    year = getIntent().getIntExtra("toYear", -1);
    //Setting my dates toString
    mo = Integer.toString(month);
    da = Integer.toString(day);
    ye = Integer.toString(year);
    //Sending to method below
    addData(destination, mo, da, ye);


}
//called from onCreate above
public void addData(String destination, String mo, String da, String ye) {
    //passing three arguments into the insertData
    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(destination.toString(), mo.toString(), da.toString(), ye.toString());
    //It would return true if data was inserted
    if (isInserted == true) {
        Toast.makeText(TripList.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(TripList.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //calling these methods to upload from database to local ArrayList
    destinationList();
    monthList();
    dayList();
    yearList();

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    //custom class
    adapter = new TruckAdapter(getApplication(), R.layout.list_custom_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    for(int i = 0; i < destinationArray.size(); i++){
        //passing destination, month, day, and year that we collected from our database to ArrayLists
        TruckDataProvider dataProvider = new TruckDataProvider(destinationArray.get(i).toString(), monthArray.get(i).toString(), dayArray.get(i).toString(), yearArray.get(i).toString(), deleteArray[0]);
        //adding the objects from TruckDataProvider to TruckAdapter
        adapter.add(dataProvider);

    }


    //when one of the destinations in the list is clicked
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //We need to increment the position by one because position starts at zero but our table starts at one
            position++;
            Intent in = new Intent("com.example.nikscodingmachine.truckersexpence.MainActivity");
            //Setting position toString
            String pO = String.valueOf(position);
            //sending position to MainActivity before we go there
            in.putExtra("toPosition", pO);
            startActivity(in);
        }

    });

}



//Adding from the database to list so my destinations will be on the list array
public void destinationList() {
    //reaching into DatabaseHelper class
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    //Moves down the rows
    while (res.moveToNext()) {
        //From the row that it moved we are getting it's colume in position 1
        //and adding it to the list array
        destinationArray.add(res.getString(1));

    }

}






}
```

---

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;


//needed for database methods below
private SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
private ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();



//our constructor
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //(ID is Primary Key which also auto increments) (... ...)
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, DESTINATION TEXT, MONTH INTEGER, DAY INTEGER, YEAR INTEGER, FUEL INTEGER, MEAL INTEGER, MAINTENANCE INTEGER, LICENCING INTEGER, TRAILER INTEGER, INSURANCE INTEGER, EXTRA INTEGER, MISCELLANEOUS INTEGER)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
//set and checking data method
public boolean insertData(String destination, String month, String day, String year) {
    contentValues.put(COL_2, destination);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, month);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,day);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,year);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
    //returns -1 if nothing is in the data base
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
//inserting the amount of fuel
public void insertFuelData(String addedResult, String Id) {
    contentValues.put(COL_1, Id);
    contentValues.put(COL_6, addedResult);
    //sendoff to method below
    ourUpdate(Id);
}

//inserting the meal amount
public void insertMealData(String addedResult, String Id) {
    contentValues.put(COL_1, Id);
    contentValues.put(COL_7, addedResult);
    //sendoff to method below
    ourUpdate(Id);
}


//getting data method
//which is used in a TripList to find and add to the list array the destinations
public Cursor getAllData(){
    //db is instance of a data base, a built in class
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}


public void deleteData(String id){
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
}

//part of update more convenient this way
public void ourUpdate(String Id){
    //built in update Id is where
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{Id});
}


}
```

---

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



public class TruckAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
TripList tList;
List list = new ArrayList();
private int pos;


public TruckAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    tList = new TripList();
}

//made a class
static class DataHandler{

    TextView title;
    TextView month;
    TextView day;
    TextView year;
    ImageView delete;


}
DataHandler handler = new DataHandler();

@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return this.list.get(position);
}


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




}
```

---

```
public class TruckDataProvider {
private String des;
private String month;
private String day;
private String year;
private int delete;

//Constructor
public TruckDataProvider(String des, String month, String day, String year, int delete){
    this.des = des;
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;
    this.delete = delete;
}

public String getDes() {
    return des;
}
public String getMonth() {
    return month;
}
public String getDay() {
    return day;
}
public String getYear() {
    return year;
}
public int getDelete() {
    return delete;
}


}
```

Comment: I have to create TripList activity tList from TruckAdapter constructor in order to pass data (In this case, position clicked) back to TripList class. What would be a solution on getting the data to TripList class while TripList is still in its lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem but still you should rewrite your code based on good example

i changed  the following

```
Context context;
public TruckAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
super(context, resource);
tList = new TripList();
this.context = context;
 }
```

the problem with calling getback

```
handler.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                tList.getBack(position, context.getApplicationContext());

            }
        });
```

and in TripList

```
 public void getBack(int del , Context ctx){
    String delete = Integer.toString(del);
       new DatabaseHelper(ctx).deleteData(delete);
}
```

======================

In your method:

```
public void getBack(int del){
    String delete = Integer.toString(del);
    myDb.deleteData(delete); 
}
```

The variable `myDB` has not been initialised and is therefore null. You should set the variable to a valid instance of your data handling class before attempting to use it

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: how's this not an answer ? should I rewrite 100 page of code so it can be count an answer  sigh

Comment: Of course it is an answer. It is just a short one. +1 to counter the answer police. If you think an answer can be improved, that is what the "Edit" button is for.

Comment: myDb is initialized at onCreate

Comment: A7mad Thanks a lot you are Awesome!!!! That did the trick. So it had to do with adding a "Context" when I pass data. Can you explain what exactly Context does here? Also I don't want to take up a lot of your time but if it's not too hard can you add the code that once someone Clicks on the "X" that whichever position was clicks would dynamically disappear right away and the list would just get rid of that position right in front of the users eyes and become one shorter. Thanks again...

Comment: [link](http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-sqlite-with-custom-listview.html) , link(http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-listview-using-custom-adapter-and-sqlite/)

Comment: [link](http://www.ahotbrew.com/android-listview-using-custom-adapter-and-sqlite/) , [link](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2013/10/database-demo-database-operations-with_13.html)